# How to check suceeding records of datagriview

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to delete a row I selected in a datagridview and the ones after it. The rows below it contain five spaces before the value of the cell. For instance, "(five spaces)popcorn. The loop should stop deleting after reading the next row and see that it doesn't have the spaces. Any idea?

Comment: I believe you can get the index of the selected row . . . and then loop using the index and checking values for the subsequent cells to verify the 5 spaces.  In the event handler you can get e.RowIndex for the selected row. Then you can do something with them: `            DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
            int RowIndex = e.RowIndex;
            if(HasFiveSpaces(dgv.Rows[RowIndex +1].Cells[1].Value)) return true;
`

Comment: "After it"?  Do you allow sorting?  If so, then "after it" has no meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, assuming the selected row does not have to be checked for spaces: note that the code first identifies the rows to delete and then afterwards deletes them in reverse order, to avoid any problems with the number of rows changing during the loop.

```
if (dgv.CurrentCell == null) return;

var spaces = new string(' ', 5);
var start = dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

if (start == dgv.Rows.Count) return;

List<int> rowsToDelete = new List<int> { start };

start++;

for (int i = start; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // Uncommitted new rows cannot be removed programatically
    if (dgv.Rows[i].IsNewRow == false
        && dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().StartsWith(spaces))
    {
        rowsToDelete.Add(i);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

rowsToDelete.Reverse(); // List.Reverse() reverses the list in place and returns void

foreach (var rowIndex in rowsToDelete)
{
    dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
}
```